# Click/toggle to reveal more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some content that I want only a few lines to be shown along with a "read more" button and then when a user clicks on the read more button, the rest of the content will be revealed by the content div dropping down (extending its height) and then the read more button would be replaced with "close".

Does anyone know of any JS Fiddle demos or tutorials with examples of similar things?

Comment: could you show your attempts in a fiddle? Could you post some code?

Comment: give it a try and show us your code with any problems you encounter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple jquery plugin as per your requirements.

It automatically shortens text within an element and add "more" link. Also display "less" link once complete text is shown.

**Usage:**

Shortens the text within 'element' and add a 'more' link.

```
$(element).shorten();
```

Add a link with text 'read more' while shortening the content of element.

```
$(element).shorten({
    moreText: 'read more'
});
```

Change the link text to 'read more' and 'read less' overriding default value 'more' and 'less'.

```
$(element).shorten({
    moreText: 'read more',
    lessText: 'read less'
});
```

Override default display 100 characters and hide text above 50 characters.

```
$(element).shorten({
    showChars: '50',
});
```

Refer to [this link](https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten) for more details.

Also you may refer to demo of the same [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/show-more-link-shortened-content/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices....
Either load the additional content into a div that has..

```
display: none;
```

on load then use jQuery

```
.show()
```

to show then content when a button is clicked.

If you have vast amounts of data or maybe images you could use and jQuery with AJAX call to load the data into the div. When doing this I would use a blank div ready to load the content into.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QWYHW/).

It uses `slideToggle()` method from jQuery. If you don't want it to *slide* then just use `toggle()`. Notice that the `long-text` element has a `display: none` style setting at first.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 0):

Basic structure of your content so that you can enable this functionality.

```
<div class="more-less">
    <div class="more-block">
        <p>The Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anything that you place into the “more-block” div will be expandable. The “more-less” div is needed to hold the More/Less link and the [...], which is added using the jQuery, saving you the time of adding those small parts.

```
$(function () {

    // The height of the content block when it's not expanded
    var adjustheight = 80;
    // The "more" link text
    var moreText = "+  More";
    // The "less" link text
    var lessText = "- Less";

    // Sets the .more-block div to the specified height and hides any content that overflows
    $(".more-less .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');

    // The section added to the bottom of the "more-less" div
    $(".more-less").append('<p class="continued">[&hellip;]</p><a href="#" class="adjust"></a>');

    $("a.adjust").text(moreText);

    $(".adjust").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
        // Hide the [...] when expanded
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
        $(this).text(lessText);
    }, function () {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
        $(this).text(moreText);
    });
});
```

Here is the demo..
http://jsfiddle.net/9FLx5/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/Hqh98/1/) using `slideToggle`

HTML:

```
Bla bla bla
<div id="content" style='display:none'>more bla bla bla bla</div>
<div id="click-me">more ...</div>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click-me").click(function () {
        var moreOrless = $("#content").is(':visible') ? 'more ...' : 
                           ' less';
        $(this).text(moreOrless);
        $("#content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```